# How can I solve Flutter Problem in release mode?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, woocommerce

My app is working normally in debug mode but when I release it shows nothing on the screen. I am using woocommerce plugin to get data.

I tried a different version of different packages, I don't know if I tried enough, but I really need help, I tested with Android Studio and Vs Code Studio but the error that I am getting is the same.

and these are the logs.

[image: screen]

```
flutter run --release
No supported devices connected.
PS C:\Users\emili\OneDrive\Documentos\Flutter Proj\ecommerce> flutter run --release
Running "flutter pub get" in ecommerce...                          27.8s
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J610FN in release mode...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_secure_storage-3.3.5\android\src\main\java\com\it_nomads\fluttersecurestorage\ciphers\RSACipher18Implementation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     163.3s (!)
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (9.3MB).
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                14.1s

Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
I/flutter ( 7256): Parameters: {page: 1, per_page: 50, status: publish, stock_status: instock}
I/flutter ( 7256): 
I/flutter ( 7256): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter ( 7256): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter ( 7256): response gotten : [{id: 8025, name: Aqua Loft Single Lever Bathroom Vanity Faucet with Side Handle - Matte Black, slug: aqua-loft-single-lever-bathroom-vanity-faucet-with-side-handle-matte-black, permalink: https://www.kubebath.com/product/aqua-loft-single-lever-bathroom-vanity-faucet-with-side-handle-matte-black/, date_created: 2020-10-23T16:30:38, date_created_gmt: 2020-10-23T16:30:38, 
date_modified: 2020-10-23T16:35:39, date_modified_gmt: 2020-10-23T16:35:39, type: simple, status: publish, featured: false, catalog_visibility: visible, description: <h2 class="subtitle">PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h2>
I/flutter ( 7256): <div class="ProductDescriptionContainer prodAccordionContent">
I/flutter ( 7256): <div>This single hole faucet is made from heavy duty brass with a matte black finish. Features ceramic disc valve for longevity and watertight functionality.</div>
I/flutter ( 7256): <p><strong>Included in the price:</strong></p>
I/flutter ( 7256): <p>• Single Lever Matte Black Faucet<br />
I/flutter ( 7256): • Extra Two Handles in Color Gold and Red.<br />
I/flutter ( 7256): • Flex Water Hoses Included for easy installatio
I/flutter ( 7256): this is query oo : products?page=1&per_page=50&status=publish&stock_status=instock
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Aqua Loft Single Lever Bathroom Vanity Faucet with Side Handle - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Aqua Loft Single Lever Bathroom Vanity Faucet with Side Handle - Chrome     
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Aqua Loft Single Lever Bathroom Vanity Faucet - Chrome
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Aqua Loft Single Lever Bathroom Vanity Faucet - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Aqua Elegance Single Lever Wide Spread Faucet - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 30" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 36" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 48" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 60" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 60" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 48" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 36" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Vetro 30" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 24" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 30" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 36" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 48" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 60" Gloss White Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 60" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 48" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 36" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 30" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Divani 24" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Kube 34" Stainless Steel Framed Mirror - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Kube 28" Stainless Steel Framed Mirror - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Kube 23" Stainless Steel Framed Mirror - Matte Black
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 59" Mirror - High Gloss White
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 59" Mirror - High Gloss Blue
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 47" Mirror - High Gloss Blue
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 47" Mirror - High Gloss White
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 35" Mirror - High Gloss White
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 35" Mirror - High Gloss Blue
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 28" Mirror - High Gloss White
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 28" Mirror - High Gloss Blue
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 22" Mirror - High Gloss White
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : AQUA 22" Mirror - High Gloss Blue
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 60" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 48" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 40" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 36" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 30" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : 24" Wide Mirror w/ Shelf - Butternut
I/flutter ( 7256): prod gotten here : Levi 63" Butternut Double Sink Modern Bathroom Vanity w/ Cubby Hole

I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 932, name: Cotton Dispenser, slug: cotton-dispenser, parent: 104, description: , display: products, image: {id: 5719, date_created: 2018-08-01T23:46:03, date_created_gmt: 2018-08-01T23:46:03, date_modified: 2018-08-01T23:46:03, date_modified_gmt: 2018-08-01T23:46:03, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/8187.jpg, name: 8187, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 1, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/932}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 649, name: De Lusso, slug: delusso, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 6527, date_created: 2019-03-11T21:54:21, date_created_gmt: 2019-03-11T21:54:21, date_modified: 2019-03-11T21:54:21, date_modified_gmt: 2019-03-11T21:54:21, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/DL48D-GW-4-1.jpg, name: DL48D-GW-4, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 24, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/649}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 1281, name: Divani, slug: divani, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 7887, date_created: 2020-10-22T15:52:15, date_created_gmt: 2020-10-22T15:52:15, date_modified: 2020-10-22T16:59:25, date_modified_gmt: 2020-10-22T16:59:25, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KD9948BLUE-2.jpg, name: KD9948BLUE-2, alt: Divani 48" Gloss Blue Vanity W/ Quartz Counter Top}, menu_order: 0, count: 10, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/1281}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 718, name: Divario, slug: divario, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 4647, date_created: 2017-09-13T20:50:48, date_created_gmt: 2017-09-13T20:50:48, date_modified: 2017-09-13T20:50:48, date_modified_gmt: 2017-09-13T20:50:48, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/D48DNW-2.jpg, name: D48DNW-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 4, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/718}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 59, name: Dolce, slug: dolce, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 5946, date_created: 2018-10-10T17:37:16, date_created_gmt: 2018-10-10T17:37:16, date_modified: 2019-11-28T22:55:33, date_modified_gmt: 2019-11-28T22:55:33, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/AD648DNW-4-Copy.jpg, name: AD648DNW-4, alt: }, menu_order: 3, count: 32, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/59}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 64, name: Double Sink Vanities, slug: double-sink-vanities, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 4193, date_created: 2017-07-04T20:46:12, date_created_gmt: 2017-07-04T20:46:12, date_modified: 2017-07-04T20:46:33, date_modified_gmt: 2017-07-04T20:46:33, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/BSL48GW-1.jpg, name: BSL48-GW, alt: Bliss 48" High Gloss White Wall Mount Modern Bathroom Vanity}, menu_order: 11, count: 60, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/64}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 128, name: Drains and Parts, slug: drains-and-parts, parent: 78, description: , display: both, image: {id: 2499, date_created: 2016-04-12T22:07:33, date_created_gmt: 2016-04-12T22:07:33, date_modified: 2016-04-12T22:07:33, date_modified_gmt: 2016-04-12T22:07:33, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/P101NO-3.jpg, name: P101NO-3, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 21, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/128}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 564, name: Eiffel, slug: eiffel, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 3778, date_created: 2016-12-22T20:24:11, date_created_gmt: 2016-12-22T20:24:11, date_modified: 2016-12-22T20:24:11, date_modified_gmt: 2016-12-22T20:24:11, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/E72-4.jpg, name: E72-4, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 3, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/564}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 78, name: Faucets, slug: faucets, parent: 0, description: , display: both, menu_order: 0, count: 54, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/78}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 482, name: Fitto, slug: fitto, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 3171, date_created: 2016-06-06T19:07:34, date_created_gmt: 2016-06-06T19:07:34, date_modified: 2016-06-06T19:07:34, date_modified_gmt: 2016-06-06T19:07:34, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/S-1200SRW-3.jpg, name: S-1200SRW-3, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 6, 
_links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/482}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 771, name: Framed Mirrors, slug: framedmirrors, parent: 129, description: , display: products, image: {id: 4928, date_created: 2017-10-06T20:14:29, date_created_gmt: 2017-10-06T20:14:29, date_modified: 2017-10-06T20:14:35, date_modified_gmt: 2017-10-06T20:14:35, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KB36GW-M-2.jpg, name: KB36GW-M, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 72, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/771}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 936, name: Free Standing Towel Rack, slug: free-standing-towel-rack, parent: 104, description: , display: products, image: {id: 5729, date_created: 2018-08-02T00:05:29, date_created_gmt: 2018-08-02T00:05:29, date_modified: 2018-08-02T00:05:29, date_modified_gmt: 2018-08-02T00:05:29, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/8216.jpg, name: 8216, alt: }, 
menu_order: 0, count: 2, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/936}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 906, name: Handheld, slug: handheld, parent: 882, description: , display: default, image: {id: 5651, date_created: 2018-07-31T03:20:57, date_created_gmt: 2018-07-31T03:20:57, date_modified: 2018-07-31T03:20:57, date_modified_gmt: 2018-07-31T03:20:57, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/AHHS1423-12.jpg, name: AHHS1423, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 
7, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/906}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 619, name: Haus, slug: haus, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 4064, date_created: 2017-06-21T19:54:38, date_created_gmt: 2017-06-21T19:54:38, date_modified: 2017-06-21T19:54:38, date_modified_gmt: 2017-06-21T19:54:38, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/CH60D-2-Copy.jpg, name: CH60D-2 &#8211; Copy, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 14, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/619}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 118, name: Kono, slug: kono, parent: 113, description: , display: products, image: {id: 4972, date_created: 2017-11-17T17:57:52, date_created_gmt: 2017-11-17T17:57:52, date_modified: 2017-11-17T17:57:52, date_modified_gmt: 2017-11-17T17:57:52, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KFST7567-2-1.jpg, name: KFST7567-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 1, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/118}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 60, name: Kube, slug: kube, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 2135, date_created: 2016-04-09T19:41:48, date_created_gmt: 2016-04-09T19:41:48, date_modified: 2016-04-09T19:41:48, date_modified_gmt: 2016-04-09T19:41:48, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/LN600GW-4.jpg, name: LN600GW-4, alt: }, menu_order: 6, count: 1, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/60}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 1195, name: Kube Elize, slug: kube-elize, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 7031, date_created: 2019-08-02T21:29:47, date_created_gmt: 
2019-08-02T21:29:47, date_modified: 2019-08-02T21:30:27, date_modified_gmt: 2019-08-02T21:30:27, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KE1100-NW_1.jpg, name: KE1100-NW, alt: Kube Elise 44" Nature Wood Wall Mount Modern Bathroom Vanity}, menu_order: 0, count: 2, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/1195}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 119, name: Lavello, slug: lavello, parent: 113, description: , display: products, image: {id: 4640, date_created: 2017-09-12T22:43:01, date_created_gmt: 2017-09-12T22:43:01, date_modified: 2017-09-12T22:43:01, date_modified_gmt: 2017-09-12T22:43:01, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/AFST9867-2.jpg, name: AFST9867-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 
2, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/119}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 439, name: LED, slug: led, parent: 129, description: , display: products, image: {id: 5455, date_created: 2018-05-18T15:38:33, date_created_gmt: 2018-05-18T15:38:33, date_modified: 2018-05-18T15:38:33, date_modified_gmt: 2018-05-18T15:38:33, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KMLED48-2.jpg, name: KMLED48-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 10, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/439}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 481, name: Levi, slug: levi, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 7599, date_created: 2020-01-23T21:47:39, date_created_gmt: 2020-01-23T21:47:39, date_modified: 2020-01-23T21:47:39, date_modified_gmt: 2020-01-23T21:47:39, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/L600RW-2.jpg, name: L600RW-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 26, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/481}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 548, name: Linear Shower Drains, slug: linear-shower-drains, parent: 83, description: , display: products, image: {id: 3738, date_created: 2016-12-01T23:02:03, date_created_gmt: 2016-12-01T23:02:03, date_modified: 2016-12-01T23:02:03, date_modified_gmt: 2016-12-01T23:02:03, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/kube-linear-drain.jpg, name: kube-linear-drain, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 15, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/548}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 76, name: Linen Side Cabinets, slug: linen-side-cabinets, parent: 75, description: , display: products, image: {id: 4770, date_created: 2017-09-23T18:51:28, date_created_gmt: 2017-09-23T18:51:28, date_modified: 2017-09-23T18:51:28, date_modified_gmt: 2017-09-23T18:51:28, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/SLBS59-NW-4.jpg, name: SLBS59-NW-4, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 18, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/76}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}       
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 124, name: Luna, slug: luna, parent: 113, description: , display: products, image: {id: 7678, date_created: 2020-01-24T17:08:54, date_created_gmt: 2020-01-24T17:08:54, date_modified: 2020-01-24T17:08:54, date_modified_gmt: 2020-01-24T17:08:54, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KFST2768-3.jpg, name: KFST2768-3, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 1, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/124}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 927, name: Magnifying Mirror, slug: magnifying-mirror, parent: 104, description: , display: products, image: {id: 5710, date_created: 2018-08-01T22:58:53, date_created_gmt: 2018-08-01T22:58:53, date_modified: 2018-08-01T22:58:53, date_modified_gmt: 2018-08-01T22:58:53, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/8166.jpg, name: 8166, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 5, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/927}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}

I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 682, name: Milano, slug: milano, parent: 53, description: , display: default, image: {id: 6529, date_created: 2019-03-11T21:58:04, date_created_gmt: 2019-03-11T21:58:04, date_modified: 2019-03-11T21:58:04, date_modified_gmt: 2019-03-11T21:58:04, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KFM48SGW-5-1.jpg, name: KFM48SGW-5, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 11, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/682}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}

I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 117, name: Solato, slug: solato, parent: 113, description: , display: products, image: {id: 3901, date_created: 2017-03-15T17:57:21, date_created_gmt: 2017-03-15T17:57:21, date_modified: 2017-03-15T17:57:21, date_modified_gmt: 2017-03-15T17:57:21, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KFST7867-2.jpg, name: KFST7867-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 1, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/117}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}
I/flutter ( 7256): category gotten here : {id: 116, name: Squadra, slug: squadra, parent: 113, description: , display: products, image: {id: 7644, date_created: 2020-01-23T22:26:21, date_created_gmt: 2020-01-23T22:26:21, date_modified: 2020-01-23T22:26:21, date_modified_gmt: 2020-01-23T22:26:21, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/KFST5063-2.jpg, name: KFST5063-2, alt: }, menu_order: 0, count: 

I/flutter ( 7256): [{id: 54, name: Anziano - Available in Canada Only, slug: anziano, parent: 53, description: , display: products, image: {id: 3626, date_created: 2016-11-23T05:00:41, date_created_gmt: 2016-11-23T05:00:41, date_modified: 2016-11-23T05:00:41, date_modified_gmt: 2016-11-23T05:00:41, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/ASL1560-GW-3-1.jpg, name: asl1560-gw-3, alt: }, menu_order: 4, count: 7, _links: {self: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/54}], collection: [{href: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories}]}}, {id: 1023, name: Aqua Chiaro, slug: aqua-chiaro, parent: 104, description: , display: products, image: {id: 6010, date_created: 2018-11-03T02:24:48, date_created_gmt: 2018-11-03T02:24:48, date_modified: 2018-11-03T02:25:05, date_modified_gmt: 2018-11-03T02:25:05, src: https://www.kubebath.com/wp-content/uploads/8220-3.jpg, name: 8220-3, alt: Aqua Chiaro by KubeBath Robe Hook With 3 Hooks - Chrome}, menu_order: 0, count: 11, _links: {self: [{hre
I/flutter ( 7256): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter ( 7256): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

Answer (score 5):

When an error occurs during the build phase, the ErrorWidget.builder callback is invoked to build the widget that is used instead of the one that failed. By default, in debug mode this shows an error message in red, and in **release mode** this shows a **gray** background.

So you change error UI in release build app by below code. You just add this code before runApp() and changes error widget in release mode.

```
void main() {
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    bool inDebug = false;
    assert(() { inDebug = true; return true; }());
    // In debug mode, use the normal error widget which shows
    // the error message:
    if (inDebug)
      return ErrorWidget(details.exception);
    // In release builds, show a yellow-on-blue message instead:
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       'Error! ${details.exception}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    );
  };
  // Here we would normally runApp() the root widget, but to demonstrate
  // the error handling we artificially fail:
  return runApp(AppRun())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last two lines.

```
Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

Which means that you have some errors in your code about UI.A common error is

```
Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
```

Try to fix all Errors which do not affect debugging but appear in the console.Then try again.
I Wish it do the trick for you